# Why arrow decoration position can not coincide with coordination point?

Tags: tikz-arrows, coordinates, tikz-decorations

I was trying to add arrow decoration to a curve in a three dimensional plot like following

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth, decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.4 with {\arrow{Stealth[round, scale = 1.5]}}}]
\centering
\draw[postaction = {decorate}] plot coordinates{(1, 3) (2, 4) (4, 1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The compiler will complain the following when I change the decoration position to `0.2` or any value near it

> Dimension too large.

I analyzed a few cases, it seems like the compiler will complain whenever the arrow decoration position is near any of the coordination point, in our case, `(2, 4)`.

Is there an explanation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the specific point, but with the fact that the curvature in the neighborhood of this point is large. Very often it is possible to draw an almost identically looking curve in a different way, and the problem does not arise.

Comment: Your code compiles without error here with MikTeX

Comment: @marmot What do you mean by drawing an almost identically looking curve?

Comment: @AndréC How did you compile? It compiles fine on my laptop. I used `xelatex` for compiling.

Comment: I compiled with pdflatex

Comment: @AndréC On my TeXLive2018 distribution the error appears with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @marmot Maybe a package has been updated on MikTeX and not yet on TexLive?

Comment: @AndréC I doubt it since I have not seen any update of the core Ti*k*Z packages in the recent past, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: @AndréC I do not have `pdflatex` but I would assume `xelatex` would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I mean by almost identical path is that there are more harmful and harmless ways to draw very similar curves.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.4 with {\arrow{Stealth[round, scale = 1.5]}}}]
 \draw[postaction = {decorate}] plot[smooth] coordinates{(1, 3) (2, 4) (4, 1)};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.3 with {\arrow{Stealth[round, scale = 1.5]}}}]
\draw[postaction = {decorate}] (1, 3) to[curve through={(1.4,3.6) .. (2, 4) .. 
(2.7,3.3) .. (3.1,2.5)}] (4, 1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I stress that I did not make too much effort in reproducing your curve. This is just to tell you that (a) yes, there can be issues and (b) they may go away if you employ alternative ways of drawing such curves.